# Thoughts on pumping up line-height

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

Minor nuisance, I find reading large paragraphs of text on Gaming SE rather cumbersome because the text is so close together.

Pumping up the line-height to 1.4 - 1.5 em, to me makes a huge difference in readability.

Examples

## Before

[image: Before Line Spacing]

## After

@ 1.5em
[image: After Line Sapcing]

Comment: It appears SO, is 130% line-height which is a tad larger than the 17px which is set on Gaming SE

Comment: Personally, I think the former picture looks cleaner, but I don't have an opinion as to the readability.

Comment: The condensed screenshot is harder to read with the current line height, but I don't have a problem reading the site itself.  Perhaps it's just the giant paragraph there that's the problem?  It could stand to be broken up regardless.

Comment: I'll adjust the line-height. I agree currently, it's not optimal.

Comment: Related/follow-up: [line-height difference between paragraphs and list items](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10253/30863)

Answer (score 5):

I have bumped the line-height to 1.4. The change will be in the next build.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mind 17px (I tested 18 and 19 and could see the difference, but it wasn't that big of a deal to me), but then I also don't read many answers that contain long paragraphs (the questions I view don't seem to work that way), and I also have a rather distinctive style of reading – I don't mind reading wide paragraphs, black-on-white text over long periods of time doesn't bother me – so I also may not have preferences that match those of many other users.